# When is Haikyuu season 3 release date?

Tags: haikyuu

I'm wonna know when will be the release date of the season 3 of Haikyuu. It says that its in this fall or in the later part of this year. But if someone know the date can you share it with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haikyuu should be released as a fall anime. There is still enough content left for the 3rd season. Both manga and anime have been well received. 
[Haikyuu Season 3 in fall](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-03-16/haikyu-volleyball-tv-anime-gets-season-3-in-fall/.99844). Not sure if this can be taken as an official confirmation though.

Though content for 4th season might not be enough so they might decide to take some time off and release OVAs.

Manga Volumes for Haikyuu. 1-17 Covered by first two seasons and only 3 Volumes left. **Manga spoilers and Season 3 speculation below**

> First half of season 3 can be covered with Final match against Ushijima easily. It can be stretched with character development of both teams.
>  Nekomas road to National is recently concluded manga arc an can fill the second part of the season.. Or vice versa since the second last episode usually has the epic finale moment. 
>  What I suspect is both Nekoma and Karasuno will be playing simultaneously and reach the finals together. It'll  give more depth to season instead of the linear storyline

Comment: It's official, Fall 2016. (from [Haikyuu Anime Official Site (Japanese)](http://www.j-haikyu.com/anime/))

Comment: Cool. Good to know. Haikyuu has been one of the best fall anime for 2 seasons now.